# They fought with/against their oppresors?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

The answer given is with. However I think "against" as correct. Can you explain why "with" is used here

Comment: Was one of their oppressors an S? If so, then it's clear that that oppressor in your question clearly lost the fight. As for your question itself, both "with" and "against" can be used with the verb "fight," albeit with different effect. "Against" tends to be reserved for more abstract adversaries— alcoholism, injustice, temptation, etc.

Comment: It's somewhat ambiguous. If you fight with your brother, you are understood to be fighting (against) him. But if you fight with another force, it's generally against a common foe. The context makes the meaning clear. **In WWll, the US fought with Britain and other allied forces against the Axis powers.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either is possibly correct, for multiple reasons. "Fought with" is ambiguous.

> Joe fought with Bob.

probably means a fight with Joe on one side and  Bob on the other. But

> Joe fought with Bob against Pat and Sam.

strongly suggests that Joe and Bob were on the same side.

"A fought with X" could mean either, and only context can  clear this up.

Thus "They fought with their oppressors" could mean the same thing as "They fought against their oppressors", or it could mean "They fought in alliance with their oppressors" which they might have done for any of several reasons.

Without context there is no rational way to mark either choice as better than the other. (I suppose one could argue that since "with" could cover either meaning, it must be correct whatever the context. That would be a very poor test in my view.)

Answer (score 1):

> They fought with

and

> They fought against

are both grammatical. Of course, they may mean completely different things. It is impossible to know which meaning is intended when you provide not one bit of context.

Now I agree that, **IN THE ABSENCE OF CONTEXT**, what seems more plausible is to fight against one’s oppressors, but there are numerous historical examples where that did not occur. One reason is that “oppressor” is a loaded term.

Comment: Note "fight with X" can mean "fight allied to X" or it can be a less formal way of saying "fought against X"

Comment: I agree. That is why I used the modal “may.” There is a double ambiguity here in that there are two contradictory meanings of “fight with” and an apparent paradox of “fight with” in the sense of “fight on the same side” as oppressors. In the absence of **ANY** relevant context, it is impossible to know for sure which ambiguity to address. I suspect the OP was confused by the conjunction of “with” and “oppressors,” and so I took that route.